# Complex compound queries in firebase V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I started work with `Firebase` new `web v9 modular` version. And for filtering result I need to use `compound queries`. I have three inputs:

1. First name
2. Last name
3. Type

When I filtering result I make request not always by three queries, sometimes I use one or two queries by request, so I don't know how mane queries I have to made, it always is different.

To solve this in `web v8 namespased` version I made this code:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
const [type, setType] = useState('')


const filterRezult = () => {
   let filterQuety = db.collection('users')

   if(firstName !== ''){
      filterQuety = filterQuety.where('data.first_name', '==', firstName)
   }

   if(lastName !== ''){
      filterQuety = filterQuety.where('data.last_name', '==', lastName)
   }

   if(type !== ''){
      filterQuety = filterQuety.where('data.type', '==', type)
   }

   await filterQuety.get().then((result) => {
      ...
   })
}
```

And it works very well. Any suggestions how to do same thing in `web v9 modular` version?

Comment: Actually yes, this solution was what I looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'd be:

```
const conditions = []

if(firstName !== ''){
   conditions.push(where('data.first_name', '==', firstName))
}

if(lastName !== ''){
   conditions.push(where('data.last_name', '==', lastName))
}

if(type !== ''){
   conditions.push(where('data.type', '==', type))
}

const filterQuery = query(collection(db, 'users'), ...conditions)
const result = await getDocs(filterQuery)
```

I highly recommend keeping the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_11) and [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#example_2_refactoring_a_function) handy during this type of exercise.

Comment: your solution works, but in `filterQuery` array must be spread operator `...conditions`

Comment: Good point.  I always forget that. I updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find out a solution of this situation.

So since all fields are non empty strings in database, I can use `Not equal (!=)` operator in conditional statement. If my state not equal to empty string, then I make a query by required condition, if state is empty string then I make query of all documents that contains non empty string data.

It should look something like that

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
const [type, setType] = useState('')

const filterRezult = async () => {
   const searchRef = collection(db, 'users')
   const querySearch = query(searchRef,
   (firstName !== ''
      ? where('data.first_name', '==', firstName)
      : where('data.first_name', '!=', firstName)
   ),
   (lastName !== ''
      ? where('data.last_name', '==', lastName)
      : where('data.last_name', '!=', lastName)
   ),
   (type !== ''
      ? where('data.type', '==', type)
      : where('data.type', '!=', type)
   }

   await getDocs(querySearch)
    .then((result) => {
       ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      ...
   })
}
```

I don't know is it best solution, but it works in my case pretty well